# Sorting UITablview with NSDictonary

Tags: xcode, uitableview, nsdictionary

I have a NSDictonary with sights in it like this:

"Eiffel Turm" for key "sight", "paris" for key "country"

"Golden Gate" for key "sight", "usa" for key "country"

"Wax Museum" for key "sight", "paris" for key "country"

Now the question is, I would like to sort my nsdictonary into a uitableview... there should be sections like paris and usa

and in this sections there should be all sights with key paris in the paris section and all sights with key usa in the usa section....

does anybody have a hint for me how to do this?

thank you for your help... i realy could need it :-)

Comment: :-D yeah... i realy dont understand these new systems here... is it possible to delete my old questions?

Comment: Yes - you can delete old questions.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to implement the UITableViewDataSource protocol.  This allows you to define multiple sections, the number of cells per section, and the cells that should be used for each of these:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

You can view an example with this here:

http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/10/uitableview-tutorial/